# Terraform conditional quantity with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need an if statement with for_each.
If it is non-prod create resource in a single subnet, if production create resources in both subnets:

```
locals {
  zone_data = {
    a = {
      subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet1.value
    }
    b = {
      subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet2.value
    }
  }
}

module "batch_server" {
     for_each = var.env_name == "non-prod" ? local.zone_data.a : local.zone_data
...
```

I get an error:

```
|----------------
    | local.zone_data is object with 2 attributes
    | local.zone_data.a is object with 1 attribute "subnet_id"

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types.
The given expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

I tried this:

```
for_each = var.env_name == "non-prod" ? [local.zone_data.a] : [local.zone_data]
```

and am getting similar error:

```
|----------------
    | local.zone_data is object with 2 attributes
    | local.zone_data.a is object with 1 attribute "subnet_id"

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types.
The given expressions are tuple and tuple, respectively.
```

Tried changing types but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for_each` expects a map with one element for each instance you want to declare. That means that if you want to declare only one instance then you need to produce a one-element map.

Here's one way to do that:

```
  for_each = var.env_name == "non-prod" ? tomap({a = local.zone_data.a}) : local.zone_data
```

This can work because both arms of the conditional produce a map of objects. The `true` arm produces a single-element map while the second produces the whole original map.

Another option to avoid the inline map construction would be to factor out a per-environment lookup table into a separate local value:

```
locals {
  all_zones = tomap({
    a = {
      subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet1.value
    }
    b = {
      subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet2.value
    }
  })
  env_zones = tomap({
    non-prod = tomap({
      for k, z in local.all_zones : k => z
      if k == "a"
    })
  })
}

module "batch_server" {
  for_each = try(local.env_zones[var.env_name], local.all_zones)

  # ...
}
```

The `try` function call here means that `local.all_zones` is the fallback to use if `var.env_name` doesn't match one of the keys in `local.env_zones`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a lookup with `var.env_name` as the key?

```
variable "env_name" {
  type = string
  default = "non_prod"
}

locals {
  zone_data = {
    prod = {
      a = {
        subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet1.value
      }
      b = {
        subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet2.value
      }
    },
    non_prod = {
      a = {
        subnet_id = data.aws_cloudformation_export.subnet1.value
      }
    }
  }
}

module "batch_server" {
     for_each = lookup(local.zone_data, var.env_name)
...
```